# Running Python Scripts From MS Office

Tags: python, excel, vba, pywin32

I have installed PythonWin installed..
I can read and write to Excel from Python, not a problem. Not the usage I need. 
All examples I have found are more complex than I need. Since, I'm moving away 
from Excel, I need a half steps for testing.

Whats the simplest way to fire off python scripts from Excel. I dont need gui.
Usage:  On open of xls excute python script. Nothing fancy.

Right now, I simply execute the scripts manually before opening xls.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

MyPythonScript.pyw ' this is where scripts should go. just one is all I need. 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Excel's `Shell` function*, e.g.

```
Sub RunExternalProg()

    Dim return_value As Double
    return_value = Shell("C:\Python26\pythonw.exe C:\my_script.py", vbHide)
    Debug.Print return_value

End Sub
```

You may need to change the path to the `pythonw` executable; depending on your setup.

> *Shell runs an executable program and returns a Variant (Double)
>   representing the program's task ID if successful, otherwise it returns zero.

Comment: After testing could I run Shell(.....) as one line Workook_open.... Or does it to return_value

Comment: Sure; make it a one-liner. There is no need to print the return value if you don't have a use for it. It may be good to check for a return-value of zero; however, thereby allowing your code to gracefully handle that possibility.